# Where can I view the output of an XCode runscript phase when building for iOS with Flutter?

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter

I am having an issue with one of my build phase scripts on XCode. I would like to view the output of my script which is trivial when I build using XCode (`cmd + 9` on OS X). However, when I build using flutter, there is no log on XCode - nothing new shows up on that tab. I have an echo statement in my build phase script I would like to see the output of. Anybody know where to find this output?

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
flutter build --verbose
```

from the command line